# Vb.net linq query on xml data

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I'm pretty new in XML and LINQ. 
I've a XLM file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Headers  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/GridLayerSchema.xsd">
<Header>
    <Name>Layer0</Name>
    <Fields FieldID="FieldID0" FieldName="FieldNameAll" FieldPosition="0"FieldPositionStart="0" FieldLenght="254" FieldEnable="true" />
</Header>
<Header>
    <Name>Layer1</Name>
    <Fields FieldID="FieldID0" FieldName="JetPosition" FieldPosition="0" FieldPositionStart="0" FieldLenght="14" FieldEnable="true" />
   <Fields FieldID="FieldID1" FieldName="Owner" FieldPosition="1" FieldPositionStart="14" FieldLenght="14" FieldEnable="true" />
   <Fields FieldID="FieldID2" FieldName="Item" FieldPosition="2" FieldPositionStart="28" FieldLenght="3" FieldEnable="true" />
 </Header>
</Headers>​
```

I need to explore the file in two ways.

- First I need to carge a combobox itemsource property with the Header.name
- Second I need to make a Datagrid header with the fiels of the select layer.

I've made a linq query for take the Name property, but dosn't work.

```
Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Layers\Layers.xml")

    Dim query = From el In xdoc...<Headers>
                Select New Header With {.Name = el.@Name}
    For Each e In query
         HeadersCollection.Add(e)
    Next
```

Comment: I haven't errors, simply I haven't result. I'll hope to find in "e" the name of Header in XML, but the query get's nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to include the namespace of XML and you can find all the `Header` elements. This will give you the correct result:-

```
Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/GridLayerSchema.xsd"
Dim query = From e1 In xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "Header")
                    Select New With {.Name = e1.Element(ns + "Name").Value}
```

Comment: Great! Work perfectly.